# PHP Image Upload keeps failing

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

The following PHP code to upload jpg/jpeg images keeps returning an upload error, [i.e. "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file." as per definition.]

Printing error code returns 0, although checking the database as well as the uploads and thumbnails directories shows that the file hasn't been added. I have double checked the directory permissions and everything looks OK.

Can here please suggest how to resolve this issue?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $target = "../uploads/"; 
        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]));
        $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        //Function to generate image thumbnails
        function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

            /* read the source image */
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
            $width = imagesx($source_image);
            $height = imagesy($source_image);

            /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
            $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

            /* create a new, "virtual" image */
            $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

            /* copy source image at a resized size */
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

            /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination with 100% quality*/
            imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest,100);
        }

        //create a mysql connection
        $dbhost                         = "localhost";
        $dbuser                         = "xxxx";
        $dbpass                         = "xxxx";
        $dbname                         = "gallery";

        // Create connection
        $conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        //check for allowed extensions
        if ((($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpg")|| ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            $photoname = $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"];
            if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $photoname))
            {
                die( '<div class="error">Sorry <b>'. $photoname . '</b> already exists</div>');
            }

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
            {
                $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO photos (photo_name,date_added) VALUES ('$photoname','$date')";
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery); 
                $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos";
                $max = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($max);
                $maxId = $row['MAX(id)'];

                $type = $_FILES["file_upload"]["type"];
                switch($type)
                {
                    case "image/jpeg":
                    $ext = ".jpeg";
                    break;
                    case "image/jpg";
                    $ext = ".jpg";
                    break;          
                }

                //define arguments for the make_thumb function
                $source = "../uploads/".$photoname;
                $destination = "../thumbnails/thumb_". $maxId . $ext ."";           
                //specify your desired width for your thumbnails
                $width = "282";
                //Finally call the make_thumb function
                make_thumb($source,$destination,$width);

                $msg = '<div class="success">
                            <b>Upload: </b>' . basename($photoname) . '<br />
                            <b>Type: </b>' . $_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] . '<br />
                            <b>Size: </b>' . ceil(($_FILES["file_upload"]["size"] / 1024)) . 'Kb<br />
                        </div>';
            }    
            else
            {
                //$msg = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
                $msg = '<div class="error">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.</div>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = '<div class="error">The file type you are trying to upload is not allowed!</div>';
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Upload Image</title>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <H3>Upload Images Here</H3>(<a href="../" target="_blank">View Gallery</a>)
        <div id="upload">
            <?php echo $msg; ?>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="file">Filename:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="upload_file" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't do `error_reporting(0)` -- when `move_uploaded_file()` gets an error, it will report it.

Comment: Commented out `error_reporting(0)`, but it doesn't provide any solution to the issue.

Comment: You sure ../images is pointing to the right directory relative to this script? Have you tried the full path: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."path/to/images/"`

Comment: Yup! Tried hard coding the path under doc-root as well. Still no luck!